# JQuery post returns querystring in address bar

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing a web form in JQuery and sending via post to a PHP page.

It looks like this:

```
$('#form-signup').submit(function(e)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        data: { name: $('#name').val() },
        url: 'signup_backend.php',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

My web form looks like this:

```
<form id="form-signup" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?=$name?>"><span class="required">*</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?=$email?>"><span class="required">*</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="tel">Telefone</label><input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" value="<?=$tel?>"><span class="required">*</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label class="blocker">Tipo de anunciante</label><span class="required">*</span>
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="advertiser" id="advertiser_1">
        <label for="advertiser_1" class="aleft">Particular</label>
        <input type="radio" name="advertiser" id="advertiser_2">
        <label for="advertiser_2" class="aleft">Imobiliária</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="password">Senha</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?=$password?>"><span class="required">*</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="check-password">Confirmação da senha</label>
        <input type="password" id="check-password" name="check_password" value="<?=$check_password?>"><span class="required">*</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="sub">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When I get the return, my Address shows this:

```
http://localhost:8888/guia/web/adm/signup.php?name=John&email=&tel=&password=&check_password=
```

Is there a way to avoid these data from my address bar?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prevent the default action of your form submit

```
$('#form-signup').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); /// <--- THIS LINE
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {name: $('#name').val()},
        url: 'signup_backend.php',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried returning false at the end of your handler (for the submit function) ?

Comment: I didn't. But the prevenDefault() solved the issue. Thanks mael!

Comment: Yep. The Jquery documentation says it is supposed to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you're not preventing the default behaviour of the `submit` event (submitting the form), so you're getting both an AJAX POST request and a normal GET form submission when your form is submitted.

Add this:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in to your `submit` event handler function to prevent the default form submission and *only* send the AJAX POST request.

Comment: Exactly Antony. I have not thought about it. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the `method='POST'` in your `form` tag. This will dictate the type as well, without putting it inside the jquery function.

`<form id="form-signup" action="POST">`

as below:

```
<form id="form-signup" action="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?=$name?>"><span class="required">*</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?=$email?>"><span class="required">*</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="tel">Telefone</label><input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" value="<?=$tel?>"><span class="required">*</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label class="blocker">Tipo de anunciante</label><span class="required">*</span>
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="advertiser" id="advertiser_1">
        <label for="advertiser_1" class="aleft">Particular</label>
        <input type="radio" name="advertiser" id="advertiser_2">
        <label for="advertiser_2" class="aleft">Imobiliária</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="password">Senha</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="<?=$password?>"><span class="required">*</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="check-password">Confirmação da senha</label>
        <input type="password" id="check-password" name="check_password" value="<?=$check_password?>"><span class="required">*</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="sub">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method that relies on `jQuery.ajax([settings])`.

```
$.ajax({
    processData : false
)};
```

URL: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings